# CAML / SPServices / JQuery Error

Tags: jquery, caml, spservices

I have the following code:

```
            function ViewItems() {

    var liHtml = ''; //Set the variable to nothing
    alert($('#categoryselect').val());
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: false,
        listName: "Items",
        CAMLQuery: "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Category'/><Value Type="Lookup">" + $('#categoryselect').val() + "</Value></Eq></Where>",
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='Image' /></ViewFields>",
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {

        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {

            liHtml = liHtml + "<h1>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</h2><br /> <img width=\"150px\" src=\"" + ($(this).attr("ows_Image")).split(", ")[0] + "\"  /><br /> <a id=" + $(this).attr("ows_ID") + " class=\"addtobasket\">[Add To Basket]</a>";
        });


     $("#tasksUL").html(liHtml); //Fill the div with the liHTML


    }
    });
    }
```

I get the following error when debugging in IE:

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)
Timestamp: Wed, 19 Mar 2014 15:27:28 UTC

```
Message: Expected '}'
Line: 74
Char: 77
Code: 0
URI: MY SP Site


Message: Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101.
Line: 2
Char: 2568
Code: 0
URI: /Assets/jquery.js
```

Line 74 is:

```
async: false,
```

I do not get the error if I don't specify a value type, however the query returns 0 results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

Type="Lookup"

Replace the double quotes with single quotes.  Should look like this:

Type='Lookup'

Comment: Not stupid.  Sometimes we just need a second pair if eyes, specially after looking at something for too long.  :)